# How to write a Switch statement for unit conversion using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Switch statement for unit conversion using Javascript.

Comment: unit is undefined set it to 0 or 1 initially

Comment: You need to get the value from the input field first. You also need to attach a listener to something so it runs in response to input, rather than on document load.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use "unit" as js variable which is already part of loaded document, need to correct your code as below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<input id="units" type="number" placeholder="Feet" value="1"/>
<script>
var unit = document.getElementById("units").value;

switch (unit) {
    case 0:
        unit = valNum/3.2808;
        break;
    case 1:
        unit = valNum / 0.0022046;
        break;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + unit;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Again, need to write separate function to load values from input field to screen. it could be event based like keypressed, mouse or simple button.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some issues in your code:

- unassigned variable `valNum`
- output was given in `case 1:`
- syntax error in `switch-case`.

```js
function calc() {
  var unit = parseInt(document.getElementById("unit").value, 10) || -1;
  var feet = parseInt(document.getElementById("feet").value, 10) || 0;
  var result = 0;
  switch (unit) {
    case 0:
      result = 'Result is: ' + (feet / 3.2808);
      break;
    case 1:
      result = 'Result is: ' + (feet / 0.0022046);
      break;
    default:
      result = 'Unit ##.##';
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Unit ##.##</p>
<input placeholder="Unit" oninput='calc()' id='unit' />
<input placeholder="Feet" oninput='calc()' id='feet' />
```